# casting column from csv as date powershell

Tags: date, powershell, csv, casting

I have a csv that is similar to this

```
"fundName","MMFcusip","ticker","AsOfDate","SumHoldingPercent"
"BlackRock OH Muni MMP/Instit","'091927236'","COIXX","2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM","100.00000000200"
"Western Asset Inst US Treas Res","'52470G841'","CIIXX","2/29/2012 12:00:00 AM","100.00000000200"
```

Using powershell, how can I cast the "asOfDate" as a date/time when using the import-csv cmdlet?

EDIT: this is the line of code that I'm currently working with

```
$measuredDate = $today.AddDays(-21)
$staleDates = Import-Csv d:\path\file.csv | Foreach-Object {$_.AsOfDate = Get-Date $_.AsOfDate} | Where-Object {asOfDate -lt $measuredDate} | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Why not cast it when you'll use the value instead that during import-csv?

Comment: That would work just fine too, though I believe I still am not sure how I would do that! I simply need to compare this date, with one stored in a variable to see if it's older than the one in the variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Import-Csv file.csv |
Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.AsOfDate) } | 
Foreach-Object {
   $_.AsOfDate = $_.AsOfDate -as [datetime]
   $_
}
```

Comment: made this change to the script and got a bunch of errors due to some rows having null ("") asOfDates. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I also edited my original post to show the exact line of code i am currently working with. thanks for the help!

Comment: can i have two "where object"? If you look above i'm already using one to narrow down my search

Comment: i also get the message [system.string] doesn't contain a method named 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

Comment: I can't tell for PowerShell v1 but it's available on v2 and above. Anyway, you can use this: Where-Object {$_.AsOfDate} | ...

Comment: That's probably the reason though I'm not sure (don't have v1 around). You should upgrade ;)

Comment: Any idea what might be wrong with this line? I'm getting a return of 0, but there should be more.

$percentTooLarge = Import-Csv path\file.csv | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -ne ""} |Foreach-Object {
 $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [int]} | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -gt 100} | Measure-Object
$numPercentTooLarge = $percentTooLarge.Count

Comment: You need to return the current object to the pipeline after assigning $_.SumHoldingPercent. The foreach scriptblock should look like: { $_.SumHoldingPercent = $_.SumHoldingPercent -as [int]; $_}

Comment: hmmm, still not returning anything

Comment: Run the command one pipeline at a time and find where it fails. First run: Import-Csv path\file.csv | Where-Object {$_.SumHoldingPercent -ne ""}, check the output, then add the next command in chain, do so until the end of the commands, only when you figured out where it fails and corrected the issue, assign it to a variable.