# import xlsx converted to csv to powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I need to import csv file to my PS script. In the same script I have a function to convert an xlsx file to csv, which I need to import. But I can't find a way to do that. I tried three approaches:

```
$CSVLicence = Import-Csv (ConvertXLSX -File $Licence) -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8
```

Where ConvertXLSX is the function to convert xlsx to csv, $Licence is a variable defined at the beginning of the script. The second approach is this:

```
$CSVfile = ConvertXLSX -File $Licence
$CSVLicence = ImportCsv $CSVfile -Delimiter "," -Encoding UTF8
```

In both cases I get an error message on the column right after "Import-Csv", that argument Path is null or empty.

The third approach was defining the path literally, which is not really a good solution, but should work, if executor of the file runs it in correct folder and uses correct file name. In this case I get an error "The member "Proemail Exchg Business" is already present" in front of the "Import-Csv" cmdlet

The csv file gets created and it looks precisely as it should, so there's obviously not an error in the converting function.

The ConvertXLSX function is defined like this:

```
$Licence = "licence"
Function ConvertXLSX ($File)
{
 $PWD = "r:\Licence\"
 $ExcelFile = $PWD + $File + ".xlsx"
 $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
 $Excel.Visible = $false
 $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
 $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)
 foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "Pridani"})
 {
  $ws.SaveAs($PWD + $File + ".csv",6)
 }
 $Excel.Quit()
}
ConvertXLSX -File $Licence
```

The function creates the csv file successfully, without any problems

Comment: `Import-Csv` only works with files.  You'd need to write the output of `ConvertXLSX` to file, THEN import it.  Alternatively, use `ConvertFrom-Csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheIncorrigible1 explained the issue quite well. Now that you've edited the question to add the `ConvertXLSX` function, we can build on that to get a solution that fits.

---

```
$ws.SaveAs($PWD + $File + ".csv",6)
```

This part is the save to the filename `$PWD + $File + ".csv"`. The number `6` represents the [CSV XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel).

The function does not return anything, just performs an action on external file. That's why you are getting the null or empty error. We can get it to return the file path, or to return the data in an object and use `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Given your code, the object would require more work as you already have the file path there.
To return file path, change:

```
}
 $Excel.Quit()
}
```

To:

```
}
 $Excel.Quit()
 return $($PWD + $File + ".csv")
}
```

You code should then work.

---

You could improve it's readability and conciseness more:

- Assign the CSV filename to a variable.
- Avoid assigning to `$PWD` as it's an alias for [`Get-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-location?view=powershell-5.1)
- Get rid of the `foreach`. You are only getting one sheet and saving that sheet at the moment. If you are doing for multiple sheets, you will have to thing how to pass the multiple paths/object to `Import-Csv`/`ConvertFrom-Csv`

Putting it all together:

```
$Licence = "licence"

Function ConvertXLSX ($File)
{
    $rootDir   = "r:\Licence\"
    $ExcelFile = $rootDir + $File + ".xlsx"
    $CSVFile   = $ExcelFile.Replace(".xlsx",".csv")

    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible = $false
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

    $wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile)
    $ws = $wb.Worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "Pridani"})
    $ws.SaveAs($CSVFile,6)

    $Excel.Quit()
    return CSVFile
}

ConvertXLSX -File $Licence
```

---

> I get an error "The member "Proemail Exchg Business" is already present" in front of the "Import-Csv" cmdlet

This one is handled in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806928/import-csv-member-already-present-issue). Short version is you have two columns with *"Proemail Exchg Business"* in the first row.

PowerShell creates an object from the CSV: the column headers must be unique. Either fix in the excel sheet, or manually specify unique headers using `-Header` as in linked post.

Comment: Thank you. Although I can't use the CSVFile variable to actually replace the xlsx file, I made it work as I need to. I need to compare the xlsx file to a csv file, so I first have to convert the xlsx to csv and then compare the two. After the script is finished, I'll delete the converted file again. As the xlsx file is managed manually, it can't be kept in csv permanently. As for the two same columns, there was one column hidden and I didn't notice it in the original xlsx file, so I was confused why is it giving this error

Comment: Now I'm struggling with another problem. One column in the file is "Date added". It's in format M/d/yyyy. I want to import only rows, where this date is after a date specified earlier. I have `where {$_.'Date Added' -gt $DateStart}` after pipe, but that doesn't work, all rows are added. When I try `where {$_.'Date Added'.Date -gt $DateStart}`, no rows are added. Can I specify date format inside of the condition? I guess that's most likely the problem.

Comment: @PetrSynek [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585289/casting-column-from-csv-as-date-powershell). If you're still having issues, I recommend asking a new question as this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently using the wrong cmdlet.  `Import-Csv` is designed to be used with a `file.csv`, not a string object or otherwise.  There is a cmdlet that exists for that purpose, `ConvertFrom-Csv`, that takes an `-InputObject` parameter (indicating it takes pipeline input).

```
PS C:\> Get-Help -Name 'ConvertFrom-Csv'

SYNTAX
    ConvertFrom-Csv [-InputObject] <PSObject[]> [[-Delimiter] <Char>] [-Header <String[]>]
```

Used in your example:

```
## Declaration of the delimiter is unnecessary when it's a comma
$CSVLicense = ConvertXLSX -File $Licence | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it loads no data. Strange thing is, that this works fine for another csv file I'm importing, since I need to compare it with the other one:
    $Report = Read-Host "Název souboru"
    $Activity = Import-Csv ("r:\Licence\" + $Report + ".csv") -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8

Comment: @PetrSynek How is `ConvertXLSX` defined?  That's not a built-in cmdlet.  Does it output to a directory? to a variable?  what does it output?

Comment: You can find the function here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1a338ff-f433-4d65-bb47-c16cb764e0f1/convert-excel-xlsx-to-csv-using-powershell?forum=sharepointcustomization